# Winform: Trouble updating combobox

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am working on a Windows Form using Powershell that will query a print server for all Printers Installed (function: FetchPrinters). I have a button added to run the FetchPrinters function.

```
Function:

    $Global:PrintServer = ""
function FetchPrinters {
    $printerTxtFileLocation = 'C:\Temp\PrinterList.csv'
    $outputBox.text = "Fetching list of printers on $Global:PrintServer"
    # $Global:PrintServer = $Global:DropDownBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Get-Printer -ComputerName "$Global:PrintServer" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive | Out-File -Force -Encoding utf8 -FilePath "$printerTxtFileLocation"
    $PrinterList = Get-Content -Path "$printerTxtFileLocation" -Encoding UTF8 -Force
    foreach ($Printer in $PrinterList) {
        $DropDownBox2.ResetText()
        [void] $DropDownBox2.Items.Add($Printer)
    }
}
```

In Dropdownbox1, there will be a list of sites (location), that when selected will determine what Print Server to query.

```
    $DropDownBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox 

$DropDownBox1.Text = "Select Site Name"

$DropDownBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(190, 20)

$DropDownBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)

$Sites = @(

    'Site 1',

    'Site 2',

    'Site 3',

    'Site 4',

    'Site 5',

    'Site 6'

    'Site 7'

)


ForEach ($Site in $Sites) {

    $DropDownBox1.Items.Add($Site) | Out-Null

}


$Global:DropDownBox1_SelectedIndexChanged = {

    Switch ($DropDownBox1.Text) {

        'Site 1' { $Global:PrintServer = "\\Printserver1" }

        'Site 2' { $PrintServer = "\\Printserver2" }

        'Site 3' { $PrintServer = "\\Printserver3" }

        'Site 4' { $PrintServer = "\\Printserver3" }

        'Site 5' { $PrintServer = "\\Printserver4" }

        'Site 6' { $PrintServer = "\\Printserver5" }

        'Site 7' { $PrintServer = "\\Printserver6" }

    }

}

$DropDownBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($Global:DropDownBox1_SelectedIndexChanged)

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox1)
```

In Dropdownbox2 there will be the list of printers available to install

```
    $DropDownBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

$DropDownBox2.Text = "Select the Printer to install"

$DropDownBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20, 60) 

$DropDownBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 20) 

$DropDownBox2.DropDownHeight = 200


$DropDownBox2.add_SelectedIndexChanged({ })

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox2)
```

As is, everything works fine, I can select a site in Drowndownbox1, hit Fetch Printers button, Dropdownbox2 shows the printers available for that site.

The issue I'm having is when I attempt to select another site (in the same form), and hit the Fetch Printers button, the $Printers variable  is retaining it's old data it looks like, so the Dropdownbox2 contains Printers from the previous query, and the current.

Ideally whenever I select a site, hit fetch printers, dropdownbox2 contains info only for that Site.

I've tried using the Clear-Variable cmdlet, but it's doesn't seem to do the trick, but it's also possible I am doing something wrong, and not thinking of this correctly.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like adding:

```
$dropdownbox2.Items.Clear()
```

... to my function does what I need. Could have sworn I tried this, but maybe the syntax was wrong.